# Embedded electronics interaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, embedded, touch-event

I am working with some embedded hardware and iOS.  I have three areas on the screen that need to be touched.  Depending on where the finger is in each area it will set an intensity and set a device number.  As long as the finger is touching the screen the device needs to remain active and as the finger moves across the areas it will give each device a new intensity along.

So think of it as three squares side by side.  When you press in square one device one activates and stay on as long as the finger is pressing in that square.  When the finger slides to square two device two is activated and device one is deactivated.  Now the other side of this equation that needs to be solved is that as you get close to the edge where square 1 and square 2 meet the inanity number needs to get modified.  I really when the finger is touching both square edges bot devices will be on but at a lower intensity.

Now, my question is what function should I use in iOs to accomplish this.  Do I use a bunch of button and just read their pressed states or do I use a swipe gesture and just track where the finger is.  What are you guys thinking as the best way to track this?

Comment: "when the finger is touching both square edges both devices will be on but at a lower intensity" -- not sure how you'd use abutted UIControls like UIButtons to do this.  The touch events are going to go to one or the other and not both.

Comment: So do you think instead of using three button I should use several more and each button would have the code that would drive the intensity of the hardware

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to put three UIImageView's on the screen to display the squares.  Then override `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded`, and `touchesCancelled` in the view controller's `.m` file.  You can retrieve the location of the touch with code like this

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog( @"touchesBegan at point %@", NSStringFromCGPoint( point ) );
}
```